# Generating a game board with squares in a rectangle

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, scala, immutability

I am trying to generate a game board (similar to a Monopoly board). I am new to Scala and am thinking that there may be a better way to do this. But improvements to the code are also welcome.

```
class BoardGenerator(squaresPerPlayer: Int, numberOfPlayers: Int) {
  val directionTuples = Array((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1))

  def generate: List[Square] = {
    val squaresPerSide = squaresPerPlayer * numberOfPlayers / 4

    def generateBoard(squaresLeft: Int, direction: Int, x: Int, y: Int): List[Square] = {
      if (direction == 4)
        Nil
      else if (squaresLeft > 1)
        Square(x, y) :: generateBoard(squaresLeft - 1, direction,
          x + directionTuples(direction)._1, y + directionTuples(direction)._2)
      else
        Square(x, y) :: generateBoard(squaresPerSide, direction + 1,
          x + directionTuples(direction)._1, y + directionTuples(direction)._2)
    }
    generateBoard(squaresPerSide, 0, 0, 0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `directions` as a variable name instead of `directionTuples`.
- Instead of having a bunch of `if`s in `generateBoard`, use pattern matching.
- Instead of passing `x: Int, y: Int` in `generateBoard`, just pass a tuple which you could call `currentPos`.  You could define a function to add the direction tuple with the `currentPos` tuple instead of typing `x + directionTuples(direction)._1, y + directionTuples(direction)._2` twice.  (There might actually be a very easy way to add `(Int, Int) + (Int, Int)` in Scala, but I can't think of it right now.)

Comment: Regarding your second point.. I am testing different values for the different blocks. Can I do that with pattern matching?

Comment: Sorry, I did not think about that, but yes you can.  You can pattern match on the tuple `(direction, squaresLeft)`.  I'll admit that it's arguably not cleaner than using `if`s.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your latest code looks fairly sharp. However, after translating your code to something I could test, I noticed a pattern that could be captured with the code below:

```
def generate: List[Square] = {

  def generateSquareList(max: Int) = 
    for {
      i <- (0 to max).toList
      j <- (0 to max).toList
      if i == 0 || i == max || j == 0 || j == max
    } yield Square((i, j))

  generateSquareList(squaresPerSide)
}
```

That is, this solution produces the same output as yours does for the tests that I performed. The intuition: you are essentially building a grid-graph sans the middle-parts. So we iterate over the range of possible points, but only keep those which are on the exterior.

Answer (score 1):

With the input from @toto2, and some changes on my own, the following is the solution that I came up with, which I think is better than what I had. Posting so that anyone interested can take a look.
Changes done

Passed a tuple like @toto2 suggested to generate board

Renamed variables and method name

Added a new method to add two tuples like @toto2 suggested

Removed the direction parameter from the `generateBoard` method and 
derived the direction by the parameter `squaresLeft`.

`squaresLeft` now represents the total squares left and not the

squares left for the particular side

Removed usage of `Nil`

```
class SimpleRingGenerator(squaresPerPlayer: Int, numberOfPlayers: Int) extends RingGenerator {
  if (squaresPerPlayer % 4 != 0) throw InvalidNumberOfSquaresPerPlayer()
  private val directions = Array((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1))
  private val totalSquares: Int = squaresPerPlayer * numberOfPlayers
  private val squaresPerSide = totalSquares / 4

  def generate: List[Square] = {

    def generateSquareList(squaresLeft: Int, nextSquarePosition: (Int, Int)): List[Square] = {
      if (squaresLeft == 1)
        List(Square(nextSquarePosition))
      else {
        val direction: (Int, Int) = directions((totalSquares - squaresLeft) / squaresPerSide)
        Square(nextSquarePosition) :: generateSquareList(squaresLeft - 1, add(nextSquarePosition, direction))
      }
    }

    def add(first: (Int, Int), second: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int) = {
      (first._1 + second._1, first._2 + second._2)
    }

    generateSquareList(squaresPerSide * 4, (0, 0))
  }
}
```